# Problems with if equals 0

Tags: php

'If greater than 1' works...

```
if (count($resort_results) > 0 && $resort_results['total'] > 0) :
```

'If equals to 0' doesn't work...

```
if (count($resort_results) == 0 && $resort_results['total'] == 0) :
```

When output of `$resort_results` is:-

```
array(2) { ["total"]=> string(1) "0" ["results"]=> array(0) { } }
```

I'm probably missing the obvious but why can't I say if `$resort_results` is zero?

Comment: Because count of `$resort_results` isn't `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression can never be true:

```
count($resort_results) == 0 && $resort_results['total'] == 0
```

If the `$resort_results['total']` key exists, then `count($resort_results)` must be at least 1 by definition.

If that array is like this, its count is 2.

```
array(2) { ["total"]=> string(1) "0" ["results"]=> array(0) { } }
//    ^ That's what this 2 means
```

Maybe you meant

```
if (count($resort_results['results']) == 0 && $resort_results['total'] == 0)
```

Just from context I would assume `total` is a single value and `results` contains 0 or more results.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was meant to do - I see now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your data...

```
array(2) { ["total"]=> string(1) "0" ["results"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Then the size of the array is hinted at the start - 2.  So when you check

```
if (count($resort_results) == 0 && $resort_results['total'] == 0) :
```

The first part is saying if it contains no values, so why bother checking the value if it has no values!

A more common way is to check if the field is not empty and then check the values...

```
if ( !empty($resort_results['total']) && $resort_results['total'] == 0) :
```

Answer (score 0):

put three equal when int result

if (count($resort_results) === 0 && $resort_results['total'] === 0) :

Comment: `===` also check type of values that `0` isn't equal with `'0'`